# Compiling c# code with csc

Tags: c#, csc

I have developed some code in C# with VS2010 and now I want to compile it but unfortunately I can't do so in Windows 7 and I have to do it in Windows Server 2008 because the code is accessing libraries not existing in Windows 7.

Anyways, I tried all the possible parameters with CSC but seems like I am unable to compile my code in Windows Server 2008 with CSC. I am really not sure about the command I am using:

```
CSC /out:myfile.exe c:\myCode\*.cs
```

"c:\myCode" is actually where all my cs files are located. I installed the latest version of .Net framework on my Windows Server 2008 machine. So I don't think there is any issue with that.

Please kindly help.
Thanks

Comment: What happens when you enter the command as shown in your question?

Comment: Why are you even trying to do that? copy the required assemblies from the server to a machine with visual studio and build there.

Comment: What's your error message(s)?

Comment: There is actually no error message showing...

Comment: Am I entering the right command?

Comment: Try `csc /?` and see if you get correct version...

Comment: Are you developing the application to run on a Windows Server?